# Why did so many posts in May 2023 not get any votes from anyone other than me?

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, specific-question

## Why is no one voting on good questions

I was the only one that voted on the following questions despite many of them having multiple comments from other users, and a lot of views, and ***a lot of effort in these on-topic questions:***

| Question | Views | # of users that commented but did not vote | Date asked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [MPI error in Quantum ESPRESSO during optimization of particularly large molecules](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10993/5) | 185 | 2 | 30 May 2023 |
| [What is the correct method to calculate ELF?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10883/5) | 121 | 0 | 10 May 2023 |
| [Gate potential wiith siesta/transiesta](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10994/5) | 97 | 1 | 30 May 2023 |
| [Why are my HPC calculations not running in SLURM?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10997/5) | 83 | 2 | 30 May 2023 |
| [How to allocate the correct charge in Materials Studio](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10866/5) | 61 | 0 | 8 May 2023 |
| [How do I plot ternary phase diagrams using Flory-Huggins solution theory?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10928/5) | 53 | 0 | 18 May 2023 |
| [How to define a mesoporous material in VASP (introducing the vacuum gap)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10841/5) | 43 | 1 | 4 may 2023 |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10880/5 | 42 | 0 | 9 May 2023 |
| [How to calculate the polarization caused by doping induced lattice distortion?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10991/5) | 38 | 0 | 30 May 2023 |
| [Getting CP2K to print the COLVAR info](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10863/5) | 29 | 0 | 8 May 2023 |
| [How to generate pole figures from limited amounts of area detector X-ray diffraction from thin films (explain it like I'm five years old)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10969/5) | 25 | 0 | 27 May 2023 |

It seems that the trend has continued in June 2023 and early July 2023 (maybe it continued for longer but I only looked chronologically at as many as I could "practically" examine during a single day [***sorry to the people waiting for things from me, that I spent almost all day on the unanswered queue today!***]):

| Question | Views | # of users that commented but did not vote | Date asked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11265/5 | 212 | 1 | 12 July 2023 |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11062/5 | 249 | 1 | 7 June 2023 |
| [How I can consider Van der Waals interactions between two materials in Quantum ESPRESSO?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11045/5) | 228 | 3 | 5 June 2023 |
| [Gaussian does not reproduce UV-Vis spectrum](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11064/5) | 95 | 1 | 8 June 2023 |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11267/5 | 78 | 0 | 12 July 2023 |
| [Problem with CP2K running AIMD](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11266/5) | 51 | 2 | 12 July 2023 |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11226/5 | 49 | 2 | 3 June 2023 |
| [band folding instead of unfolding](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11167/5) | 32 | 0 | 20 June 2023 |
| [why should we use rectangular supercell of graphene instead of hexagonal supercell to calculate the elastic constant (in-plane stiffness)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11044/5) | 31 | 0 | 5 June 2023 |
| [NLMO algorithm failed to converge](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11182/5) | 22 | 0 | 22 June 2023 |

## Why are so many people upvoting posts with issues?

In contrast, the following questions got an unusually high number of upvotes  during that same month, despite the questions having unfavorable issues:

- [How can we calculate transverse and longitudinal optical phonon frequencies](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10848/5)

  - 5 upvotes, despite using a big screenshot rather than text, and despite stylistic issues
- [I'm calculating the band structure with and without considering spin orbit coupling. why I need to use SOC?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10982/5)

  - 1 upvote (not from me), despite qualifying to be classified as VLQ (very low quality) due to its length, and despite 4 close votes and no response to the following comments:
  - "Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking."
  - "This question is currently marked as a low-quality question. So to avoid it from being closed, please add more details such as relevant code, input files and other appropriate details."

## Related MMSE.Meta threads

- [Why did this question not get any votes in the last 5.5 months despite getting 61 views and comments from at least 3 different people?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/366/5)
- [Why is nobody voting on this question, but so many people are voting on the comments?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/5)
- [Why did this question not get any votes in the last 6 months despite getting 49 views and 4 upvotes on a comment?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/5)
- [Why has this answer not received a single upvote in almost 6 months?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434/5)

The last of these describes [an answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10940/5) which was also in May 2023 and has still received 0 votes (including from me).